# Json Tags in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a JSON file loaded as Variant in Snowflake (Shown below)

```
with car_sales(src) as (
    select
        parse_json(column1) as src
    from
    values
        (
            '{ "MyData": {
     "DataID": "16784",
    "EmpFirstName": "Jenny",
    "EmpLastName": "Test1",
    "Description": "My Company Data",
    "Assignment": [
      {
        "AssignentId": "1077",
        "AssignentName": "Multi Location",
        "AssignentDescription": "usa",
      },
    ],
    "salary": 21557
    }, "Update": true 

}'
        )
)
```

How do I select additional Tags like Update into my SQL query.

The query I have below is showing error

```
select
    value:DataID::string as "DataID",
    value.Update ::Boolean as "Update"
from
    car_sales,
    lateral flatten(input => src:MyData:Assignment);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting on different levels. One level is flattened, the other is not:

```
with car_sales(src) as (
    select
        parse_json(column1) as src
    from
    values
        (
            '{ "MyData": {
     "DataID": "16784",
    "EmpFirstName": "Jenny",
    "EmpLastName": "Test1",
    "Description": "My Company Data",
    "Assignment": [
      {
        "AssignentId": "1077",
        "AssignentName": "Multi Location",
        "AssignentDescription": "usa",
      },
    ],
    "salary": 21557
    }, "Update": true 

}'
))
select
     src:MyData.DataID::int DATA_ID
    ,src:Update::boolean    "UPDATE"
    ,VALUE:AssignentId::int ASSIGNMENT_ID
    ,VALUE:AssignentName::string ASSIGNMENT_NAME
from
    car_sales,
    lateral flatten(input => src:MyData:Assignment);
```

Notice that the flattened levels select from "VALUE" while the non-flattened levels select from the base column name "src".

Output:

| DATA_ID | UPDATE | ASSIGNMENT_ID | ASSIGNMENT_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16784 | true | 1077 | Multi Location |

Answer (score 0):

Using column to access "single element" and flatten to access array's elements:

```
select src:MyData:DataID::string as "DataID", 
       src:Update::Boolean as "Update",
       value:AssignentId::INT
from car_sales
, lateral flatten(input => src:MyData:Assignment);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is Update a reserve word? I am getting following error -  invalid identifier '"src.Update"'

Comment: @LKOMason `src:Update` vs `src.Update` `:` has to be used